# Proguard Android obfuscates only the variable names

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm going crazy.

I followed [this](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidactivity) and [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).
I searched for a solution on StackOverflow (and other sites), but I couldn't find a solution.

I wrote an app and I want to obfuscate it.
I included the standard file `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')` and a custom file as well.

```
   -flattenpackagehierarchy obsthierarchy
   -repackageclasses obfus
   -allowaccessmodification
   -keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
   -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
   -keep class com.google.** { *;}
   -keep interface com.google.** { *;}
   -dontwarn com.google.**
   -keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
   -keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
   -keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
   -keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
   -keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
   -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
   -keepattributes *Annotation*
   -keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
   -keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
   -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
   -dontwarn okio.**
   -dontwarn rx.**
   -dontwarn retrofit.**
   -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
   -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
       @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
   }
   -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
   -dontwarn org.joda.convert.FromString
   -dontwarn org.joda.convert.ToString
```

Only the names of the variables are obfuscated, the packages, class name and methods are not.
What am I doing wrong?